# Avoid cyclic dependency in n-layer architecture in .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have created such n-layer architecture in .net core (console app):

```
Company.App
   -> reference to Company.Services
   -> reference to Company.Infrastructure

Company.Services
   -> reference to Company.Infrastructure

   + IWorkStarter
   + WorkStarter - (ExternalClient is injected)

Company.Infrastructure
   + RabbitMqConsumer - (IWorkStarter must be injected) - Cyclic dependency
   + IExternalClient
```

As you see `Services` already has a reference to `Infrastructure`. And I have to use `IWorkStarter` inside rabbit consumer as well. It seems I have no required knowledge  to separate those components in a right way. Could you please help me? The project is quite simple.

Comment: What does WorkStarter do to be required by RabbitMqConsumer? Perhaps there's a method that can be pulled out?

Comment: @Stuart It is used while consuming message. While consuming message I am parsing that message to some object and then send to work starter

Comment: So would would moving IWorkerStarter into Infrastructure fix it for you?

Comment: @Stuart But, is it right to move that interface to Infrastructure? May be I have to move RabbitConsumer to `Services`?

Comment: There will be plenty of combinations to make this compile, but you need to decide what belongs logically to what project, only you have the context to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following a design I see frequently in Clean Architecture (Onion Architecture) with ASP.NET Core.

Review the following

```
Company.App
   -> reference to Company.Services
   -> reference to Company.Infrastructure
   -> reference to Company.Core

    + Compsition Root maps everything
   
Company.Services
   -> reference to Company.Infrastructure
   -> reference to Company.Core

   + WorkStarter - (ExternalClient is injected)

Company.Infrastructure
   -> reference to Company.Core
   
   + RabbitMqConsumer - (IWorkStarter must be injected)
   
Company.Core
   + IWorkStarter
   + IExternalClient
```

Move the abstractions out into their own concern

The following reference repository provides a good example

https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

> ### The Core Project
>
> The Core project is the center of the Clean Architecture design, and all other project dependencies should point toward it. As such, it has very few external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I need. Great.